# Ansible: using a variable in another variable declaration

Tags: variables, ansible

I'm stuck trying to use a variable in another variable declaration.
Here is the code in my playbook:

```
- hosts: operate
  roles:
    - { role: dns, vargroup: 'test' }

- hosts: test
  roles:
    - common
    - certbot
    - ...
```

And now the very first lines of my dns role:

```
- debug: var=vargroup

- name: Extracting IP(s) {{vargroup}}
  vars:
    extractip: "{{ hostvars[groups['{{ vargroup }}'][0]]['ip'] }}"
  set_fact:
    newip: "{{ item.expose }}"
  with_items: 
    - '{{ extractip }}'
```

Vargroup is correclty printed in debug and my task name. But in the extractip part, i've got this error:

```
{
    "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute '{{ vargroup }}'",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Obviously, i've try hardcoding the line like:

```
    extractip: "{{ hostvars[groups['test'][0]]['ip'] }}"
```

And it worked like a charm. I really don't know how to use this var in my var declaration :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by the way quotes works in YAML. After variable substitution `'{{ extractip }}'` will become `'{{ hostvars[groups['{{ vargroup }}'][0]]['ip'] }}'`.
It will try to interprete `'{{ vargroup }}'` as a plain string instead of variable.

Just use double quotes and it will work

```
  with_items: 
    - "{{ extractip }}"
```

Since Ansible doesn't support nesting "{{ }}" construct, but you can simply remove that part and just use `"{{ hostvars[groups[vargroup][0]]['ip'] }}"`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help ! Unfortunately it is still not working :/

Comment: Try this `"{{ hostvars[groups[vargroup][0]]['ip'] }}"`

Comment: Worked ! Thank you :)
Regarding this doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names

I tried:
   extractip: "{{ hostvars[groups[{{ lookup('vars', 'vargroup') }}][0]]['ip'] }}"

Do you know why it is not working ?

Comment: Because, as explained above, you cannot nest jinja2 expression expansion markers (double curly braces). This would work: `"{{ hostvars[groups[lookup('vars', 'vargroup')][0]]['ip'] }}"`. But that is not really following the KISS principle.

Comment: Thank you guys ! I got it now :)